# Run JAR file with PSExec and CMD

Tags: c#, msbuild, psexec

I need to run a jar file on a remote machine. The jar takes several arguments.

```
psexec \\somemachine -i  /accepteula -i -u domain\user -p password  cmd /S "c:\mydir\myjar.jar" [my jar args here]
```

Can someone tell me how to do this? The closest I have gotten is getting CMD to launch but with not command.

Comment: The /s argument for cmd.exe means little.  /c, at least.  Type cmd.exe /? at the command prompt to see what these options mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
psexec \\somemachine -i  /accepteula -i -u domain\user -p password  cmd /c "java -jar c:\mydir\myjar.jar [my jar args here]"
```

?

Answer (score 1):

To run a java executable (which I assume myjar.jar is), you have to use the following command:

```
java -jar [jar name]
```

So try this:

```
psexec \\somemachine -i  /accepteula -i -u domain\user -p password  cmd /S "java -jar c:\mydir\myjar.jar" [my jar args here]
```

Comment: Thank you.. Not sure why I forgot to add java -jar. This launches cmd.exe but with no command entered.

Comment: Don't you need a /C as an argument to cmd.exe to launch java?